# Generate a table with PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to generate a table in PHP.

I need this table has 365 cells.

Each row need to contains 30 cells.

How is it possible please?

Actually, I have:

```
echo '
    <table class="table">
';

$dates = getDatesFromRange('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01');

$i=1;
$limit=30;

// $dates contains an array of 365 dates
foreach($dates as $date){

    if($i <= $limit) {
        echo '<td width="20">'.-.'</td>';
        $i++;
    }
    else {
        echo '<tr><td width="20">'.-.'</td></tr>';
        $i=1;
    }
}

echo '
    </table>
';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested loops for this:

```
$cells_per_row = 30;
$rows = ceil(count($dates)/$cells_per_row);

echo '<table class="table">';
for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for($u=0;$u<$cells_per_row;$u++){
        if(!isset($dates[$i*$cells_per_row+$u])) // stop if end of array is reached
        break;
        echo '<td width="20">'.$dates[$i*$cells_per_row+$u].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```